# Python: How can a class inherit from a function?

Tags: python

Here's a piece of code that I cannot understand:

```
class COWMeta(type):
    pass

class COWDictMeta(COWMeta):
    ....
```

I know how to create a new class in python:

```
class MyClass(BaseClass):
    ...
```

But as the manual states, 'type' is function.

> type(...)
>   Function of `__builtin__` module
>   type(object) -> the object’s type type(name, bases, dict) -> a new type

How can a class inherit from a function? And what does that piece of code mean?

Comment: And just below that it says "With three arguments, type() functions as a constructor as detailed below.", and "Return a new type object".

Comment: `type` is the base type. It just happens to be callable (i.e. executable as a function). It's not a function object. Try `repr(type)` in the interpreter to see what it is.

Comment: Why do you want to inherit from type?

Comment: @esaelPsnoroMoN: in Python, inheriting from `type` is a common pattern, and is basically the only way of creating metaclasses.

Answer (score 4):

`type` is the basic object *type* in python. Like many object types in python, it acts as a constructor for creating new types, but in it's simplest form it'll return the type of existing objects. It then *looks* like a function. Compare this to `int()` and `list()`, for example.

In python, you can create *new* types, also called metaclasses, allowing you to do all sorts of powerful and interesting tricks in Python. Basing a class definition on `type` means you are creating a new metaclass.

See [What is a metaclass in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python) for an in-depth answer on what metaclasses are.

Answer (score 2):

`type` is not a function in the same way that, eg:

```
def foo():
    pass
```

is a function. It is callable like a function (and like many other objects in Python), but it is actually *coded* as a class. `type` itself can show you this difference:

```
>>> type(type)
<class 'type'>
>>> type(foo)
<class 'function'>
```

The docs call it a 'function' not because of how it is *implemented*, but because of how it is commonly *used*. This is broadly similar to, for example, [`itertools.permutations`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations), which while not explicitly called a function by the docs *is* implied to be one:

> Return successive r length permutations of elements in the iterable.

But `itertools.permutations` is implemented as a class:

```
>>> type(itertools.permutations)
<class 'type'>
```